# Name nodes on Simulink

Tags: simulink

I'm new to Simulink, and would like to make my circuits less messy. So I'd like to know how to make a node, such as on the image bellow, which has Vin and Vout written on. My MATLAB version is 2015a.

Thanks.
[image: Example circuit]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To transmit the signal in this way, you have to use (`From` and `Goto`) blocks. 
[image]

However, in your example they are using voltage sensor along with (`From` and `Goto`) blocks. If you double click `Vout`, for example, you will see this,

[image]

Which is, from left to right, `PMC port`, `Voltage sensor`, `PS-simulink converter` and ***`Goto`*** blocks, respectively. Then we are using `From` block to receive Vout signal and plot it.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the simple label to work for me.
Type in "Label" in the library browser and attached to a node the label with a name and then add another label on a different node you would like to be attached at the other first node with the same name. See Vcap in the image. I am referencing the cap voltage with the label "Vcap" and then attaching it to the comparator circuit. Create a simple circuit using this method and see how it works with voltage and/or current sensors

[image]

Comment: I'm glad that you got it working for you. But this isn't a forum. The answer field is reserved for actual answers. Take the [tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) to check out how this Q&A site works.

Comment: @Blake Can you expand this answer and explain why it works?

Comment: Type in "Label" in the library browser and attached to a node the label with a name and then add another label on a different node you would like to be attached at the other first node with the same name.  See Vcap in the image.  I am referencing the cap voltage with the label "Vcap" and then attaching it to the comparator circuit.  Create a simple circuit using this method and see how it works with voltage and/or current sensors.

Answer (score 0):

To make nodes as per the image shared by you , you need to give GOTO and From.
https://de.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/goto.html.
The Goto block will give the input to the respective 'From' Block. For Example - If the output of your Voltage Sensor Subsystem is Vout and you need to give it on Scope , Then you need to put a GOTO block. But since GOTO block is a physiccal port from Simscape library , you need to also put PS-Simulink Converter. Now when you to a GOTO block , It will always show no 'No Goto Tag' , until you give a 'From' to it. So for every GOTO you will give a 'From'. In your Example Vout from VOltage Sensor Subsystem is GOTO block and its display on Scope will have its 'From' BLock.